# validation problem with JSF h:form and PrimeFaces p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page that is basically a create form.  The form consists of a variety of input fields and also a list of sub-elements.

To add a sub-element, you click the "add element" link which pops up a dialog box using the PrimeFaces p:dialog tag.  It's similar to the login panel demo on the prime faces page here, complete with the p:growl validation messages:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf

My problem is, when I click "add" in the dialog box I see growl validation messages for the fields in the dialog box and also the fields on the main form.  I only want to see the messages for the dialog box.

Is there a way to do this?  I tried embedding a form within a form, but it didn't work.  That is, I tried ...

```
<h:form>

  <p:messages /> <!-- show validation messages for create form contents -->

  <h:inputText value .../>

  <h:dataTable value .../> <!-- list of sub elements -->

  <h:commandLink "shows the add element dialog" ... />

  <p:growl /> <!-- shows the validation messages for dialog contents -->

  <p:dialog>

     <h:form>

       <h:inputText value .../>

       <p:commandButton "validate dialog box fields then add the item to the list" .../>

     </h:form>

  </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

... but that didn't work.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all is that you cannot embed one form in another. I think it is not valid html.

`p:growl` behaves like `h:messages`. It shows messages for all elements of the page (not limited to one form). You can limit it to global messages only (messages with no `id`) by setting the `globalOnly="true"` attribute.

Change your commandButton to update only the `p:growl` and make sure that it is an ajax request that is fired by your commandButton (`ajax=true`). The `p:commandButton` has `ajax=true` as default behaviour. So if you didn't change it explicitly, then it is an ajax request.

Comment: Hi Matt, I did everything you said.  And it works but I still have my side effect.  Not sure the best way to approach it.  Imagine it this way: I have a form with a "Full Name" field and a "Phone Numbers" list (in a h:dataTable).  To add a phone number to the list, click "Add Phone Number" and the dialog box appears, enter a phone number in dialog box and click the "Add" button.  The problem is the growl shows me the validation message "Value required for Full Name" because it's validating all fields on the page, not just the ones on the dialog box.  The "Add" is an ajax request.

Comment: Ah, I think you should put the input field for the full name in a different form than the dialog. If you submit a form, all elements will be validated even if only a subset is updated. So use two forms (not nested!).